# How to design, Order and State in DDD?

Tags: domain-driven-design

Supose I have an order and it can be in an state.

Order it would be the root entity, and State another root entity in the same bundary context than the order.

I was thinking that State it should be an entity too because it would be in this way:

```
State
{
   long Id,
   string State;
   bool AllowModifyOrder;
   bool AllowAceptorder;
   //another properties that define what is possible to do in the state.
}
```

So I think it is needed that the State it is another entity, not a value object. But I am not sure if this it would be the best option.

Another doubt that I have is that the order need a property to point to the state, but not to the class, but to the ID, because I have read that an entity it is better to use the ID instead of the object, to avoid try to access or modify a root entity from another. But in this case, when I need some data of the state, for example if it can be accepted or if it can be modify. How could I do that if I only have the ID of the state?

Thanks.

Comment: If you have a fixed count of different states, for example paid, delivered, etc, then you can simply replace states instead of editing them. As of the id, when you read the order entity, then it should automatically read the stat entity too from the database. They always change together. Aggregate root is a boundary of change. When you save data you make a snapshot of the actual aggregate root with all of its properties. As far as I understand DDD.

Comment: I know to have fixed number of states it could be a solution, but if I have to added a new one, I have to modify the code. In the other way, I only have to add a new state in the database. Anyway, I would like to know how to do in this general case, how to get the information of an entity root that is related with another entity, if it is advised to have only the ID of the root entity.

Comment: You say the Order can be in a State. This statement implies that State is a property of the Order aggregate. Why are you modeling the order state as a separate aggregate? If you just put the properties in the Order aggregate, your problems disappear, right?

Comment: @FrancescCastells and how could I manage the states? For example, I have an state create, and I want to create a new state, sent. Is it correct create it from order? Because this state can be used for many orders.

Comment: I don't really understand the problem. How can an Order state be shared? The way I see it, the Order aggregate should have the State property (normally it's an integer, where 1, 2, 3... are defined. for example, as Pending, Accepted, Cancelled...) and the Order aggregate knows (programatically) that when the State is Cancelled, it cannot be modified or accepted. If you want to make a programable state machine, I don't think aggregates are the right pattern.

Comment: Who has the information to know if it can be change the status is the status entity. For example, Status accepted has a bool CanBeAccepted to false, because it is Accepted. If I only have the ID of the status in the order, I have to hardcode that 1 means accepted and I can do X actions, if it is 2 Y actions... If I have in the status state what is it possible to do, it is more flexible, reduce code and allows to add new status without modifing the code.

Answer (score 0):

Your State has to be a property of an Order because your Ubiquitous Language says "An Order can be in a state". You are tieing yourself too closely to the Database Model. That's why you have Id's and properties that look like Columns in your class.

If an Order has a State and there's a finite amount of States, then your State can be modeled as an Enum. Take this C# code for an example:

```
public Enum OrderState {
  Draft,
  Open,
  Closed
}

public class Order {
  OrderState State { get; private set; }
}
```

Your Repositories and Factories will take care of translating what you have in your Database and Inputs into Domain Classes like Order.

Comment: But If I have states as enum, I can't have properties like AllowsAcept or another information that I need, so it is I think state in this case as a root aggregate, and if it is a root aggreate, it is recommended that Order only refers to its ID, not to the object. Also in DDD entities need an ID, values object are which don't need and ID.

Comment: You are tying your domain too closely to the Tables. Your Entities are not simply DAO (data access objects). You have to let your Ubiquitous Language guide you to your design.
In this case, I ask: What in your domain is able to "Allow an Accept"? For example: If your Orders can be "accepted" then you can have a Property Order.IsAcceptable. Or, my preferrence is to have a new Entity called "AcceptableOrder" that has behaviors (methods) only relevant to Orders in that state. Your Repo and Factory will be responsible for returning an instance of it based on information in the database.

Comment: And if I have to added a new state in the futere? How could I do? I have to modify the code to add a new concrete class for this new state?

Comment: If your new state comes with new behavior, then that makes sense. You create your new class and add your behavior. If your states do not drive unique (or complex) behaviors, using enums is probably easier to maintain and will fit your UL better. If you are looking for ease for adding new status, I suppose you can use a simple string but it's not expressive enough and it's relatively complex to validate consistently across the codebase. This is the fun of design, you make decisions based on needs and a future you can't actually predict (so I practice YAGNI).